# Changing natbib style from authoryear to numbered for a small section

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am writing a paper for a journal that requires citations in author-year format. I can produce this using `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\cite, \citep` commands as shown below.

[image]

However, I want to produce a table that summarizes methods used by multiple papers and for this table only, I would like to have numeric citations next to the text as follows.

[image]

I produced the table output in the second image by using usepackage[numbers]{natbib} and \cite{}. For the first image output I used usepackage{natbib} and \cite and \citep respectively.

What is the best way to achieve numeric citation for only a part of the paper without effecting the author-year citation style of the remaining paper?

Comment: You could supply the correspondence in the table caption.

Comment: Yes, but I would have to be very careful every time I introduce a new reference to the bib file as the numbers would change. I was hoping for a more systematic way to handle it.

Comment: I'd simply use 1 for the first reference in the table, 2 for the second one and so on.

Comment: You should show a complete example so that we don't have to guess how you added the numbers to the bibliography.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I produced the table output in the second image by using `usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and `\cite{}`. For the first image output I used `usepackage{natbib}` and `\cite` and `\citep` respectively.

Comment: Sure but as you don't want to use numbers outside the table, how should someone know to which bib entry they refer? Do the bib entries have numbers?

Comment: No the bib entries wouldn't have the numbers when I use `\usepackage{natbib}` without the `[numbers]` option. You are right, it would be very hard for someone to refer to the bibliography according to the numbers. I need to find some other way to concisely refer to the citations in the table.